# Next.js website successfully deployed on Vercel but showing internal server error after deployment on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, vercel, internal-server-error, next.js13

I have built a Next.js website and successfully deployed it on Vercel. The deployment on Vercel is functioning correctly without any errors. However, when I attempt to deploy the website on AWS Amplify, the provisioning, build, and deployment processes complete without any errors. But when I open the link provided after the deployment on AWS Amplify, it shows an internal server error. I'm seeking guidance on how to effectively debug this issue.

i have tried to deploy the app again but it is giving the same error

Comment: Have you looked to see which versions of Vercel AWS Amplify supports? Also, could you check the build logs to locate the error?

Comment: There is no error in the build the application is build successfully